# How to show messages from room database in the recycler view?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room

I am saving the messages in room database and want to show them as user reopens the fragment as it is, messages on opposite sides like a whatsapp chat fragment but as the system is giving reponse  the user message is getting replaced and not showing after reopening the app as well only the system generated messages are showing in the reyclcer view.

The entity class is

```
@Entity(tableName = "messages")
data class  Conversation(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "sent") val sent: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "received") var received : String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "timestamp") val timestamp: Long
)
```

this is the main fragment onviewcreated part

```
    database = ConversationDatabase.getDatabase(requireContext())       
             
    
    // conversationViewModel.getUserMessages().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    // messages ->
    //                     messageRVAdapter.setconversationHistory(messages)
    //                 }
    
 conversationViewModel.getAllMessages().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { messages ->
           Log.d("MyApp", "Observed user messages in Fragment getallmessages: $messages")
           messageRVAdapter.setconversationHistory(messages)
    }
            
         private fun getAllMessages(dao: ConversationDao, messageRVAdapter: MessageRVAdapter) {
                    val userMessages = dao.getUserMessages()
                    val allMessages = dao.getAllMessages()
            
                    userMessages.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { userConversationList ->
                        val userMessages = userConversationList.map { conversation ->
                            MessageRVModel(conversation.sent, conversation.received, System.currentTimeMillis())
                        }
                        messageRVAdapter.setconversationHistory(userMessages)
                    }
            
                    allMessages.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { allConversationList ->
                        val allMessages = allConversationList.map { conversation ->
                            MessageRVModel(conversation.sent, conversation.received, System.currentTimeMillis())
                        }
                        messageRVAdapter.setconversationHistory(allMessages)
                    }
                }
```

this the adapter class

```
    class MessageRVAdapter(private var messageList: ArrayList<MessageRVModel>):
        RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    
        class RequestMessageViewHolder(ItemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(ItemView){
            val requestMsgTV: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.request_text)
        }
        class ResponseMessageViewHolder(ItemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(ItemView){
            val responseMsgTV: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.response_text)
        }
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            val view: View
    //        return if(viewType == 0){
            return when (viewType) {
                0 -> {
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.request_rv_item, parent, false)
                    RequestMessageViewHolder(view)
                }
    //        else{
                1 -> {
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.response_rv_item, parent, false)
                    ResponseMessageViewHolder(view)
                }
                else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid view type")
    
            }
        }
                       
fun addMessage(messages: MessageRVModel) {
        messageList.add(messages)
        notifyItemInserted(messageList.size - 1)
    }

    fun updateMessages(messages: List<MessageRVModel>) {
    val previousSize = messageList.size
    messageList.clear()
    messageList.addAll(messages)
    messageList.sortBy { it.timestamp }
    notifyDataSetChanged()
} 
fun setconversationHistory(messages: List<MessageRVModel>) {
    messageList.clear()
    messageList.addAll(messages)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
} 
}
```

this is the viewmodel class

```
class ConversationViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
 fun setConversationHistory(): LiveData<List<MessageRVModel>> {
        return chatBot.getAllMessages()
    }  fun getUserMessages(): LiveData<List<MessageRVModel>> {
        return chatBot.getUserMessages()
    }    fun getAllMessages(): LiveData<List<MessageRVModel>> {
        return chatBot.getAllMessages().map { conversationList ->
            conversationList.map { conversation ->
                MessageRVModel(conversation.sent, conversation.received,  conversation.timestamp)
            }
        }
    }  }
```

this is the chatbot class

```
class ChatBot(private val conversationDao: ConversationDao) {
    suspend fun insertMessage(sent: String, received: String) {
        val timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val conversation = Conversation(id = 0, sent = sent, received = received, timestamp = timestamp)
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            conversationDao.insertMessage(conversation)
        }

    } 
    }
     fun getAllMessages(): LiveData<List<MessageRVModel>> {
        return conversationDao.getAllMessages().map { conversationList ->
            conversationList.map { conversation ->
                MessageRVModel(conversation.sent, conversation.received,  conversation.timestamp)
            }
        }
    }

    fun getUserMessages(): LiveData<List<MessageRVModel>> {
        return conversationDao.getUserMessages().map { conversationList ->
            conversationList.map { conversation ->
                MessageRVModel(conversation.sent, conversation.received,  conversation.timestamp)
            }
        }
    }}
```

this is the dao

```
@Dao
interface ConversationDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM messages")
    fun getAllMessages(): LiveData<List<Conversation>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sent = 'me'")
    fun getUserMessages(): LiveData<List<Conversation>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
     suspend fun insertMessage(messages: Conversation)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteMessage(messages: Conversation)
}
```

this is the dataclass

```
 data class MessageRVModel(
        var sent: String,
        var received: String,
        val timestamp: Long
       )
    class Message{
        var SENT_BY_ME = "me"
        var SENT_BY_SYSTEM = "system"
    }
```

I am not getting where the issue is which is causing the user message to not fetch or show  from the database to the recycler view and also it is replacing with api response every time new api response is added in the recycler view  if you have any solution to this please help.

Comment: Can you add the code of  onBindViewHolder() method of the adapter as well. You said database has all the conversations, so there isn't a problem with that.

Comment: @PawanSinghHarariya yes override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val sent = messageList.get(position).sent
        val message = messageList[position]
        when(holder){ is RequestMessageViewHolder  -> {    val requestHolder = holder as RequestMessageViewHolder
                requestHolder.requestMsgTV.text = message.received}
           is ResponseMessageViewHolder -> {
                val responseHolder = holder as ResponseMessageViewHolder
                responseHolder.responseMsgTV.text = message.received
            }
        }

Comment: @PawanSinghHarariya actually no because the solution you provided was not working properly and gave the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `getItemViewType()` method, so that the recycler view knows which view type to use for which position.

```
// you need to tell for which position which view type to use
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val sent = messageList.get(position).sent
        if(sent.equals("me"))
            return 1;  //   ResponseMessageViewHolder for me
        return 0;     //    RequestMessageViewHolder for other
    }
```

Comment: i have implemented override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when(messageList[position].sent){
            "me" -> 0
//            "ai" -> 1
            else -> 1
        }} override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return messageList.size
    }

Comment: You can try to log the data to see where its going wrong. First log the messages from the list that you get back from dao. Second, log the messages in the messageList of your adapter.

Comment: as you said, I got the log and the user and the system messages are retrieving from the database perfectly in the manner -- sent=abc , received= xyz . And in the fragment code conversationViewModel.getAllMessages().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { messages ->
   Log.d("MyApp", "Observed user messages in Fragment getallmessages: $messages") messageRVAdapter.setconversationHistory(messages)} the log is Observed user messages in Fragment getallmessages: [MessageRVModel(sent=abc, received= xyz, timestamp=1692087480867)  but still the user messages are not showing in recycler view

Comment: when inserting a new user message the log is giving == Inserting message in database from chatbot: sent=abc, received= xyz,,  all messages LiveData changed viewmodel: [], Retrieved message from database: sent=abc, received= xyz, Observed user messages in Fragment getallmessages: [MessageRVModel(sent=abc, received=xyz,, timestamp=1692212447040), MessageRVModel(sent=fkjh, received=rsgt timestamp=1692218285158)]

Comment: then also only the system messages are adding and not the user messages, even after retrieving both the messages from the database, if you have any suggestion please give.

Comment: I don't completely understand your data models. The `sent` field in your Conversation data class is for specifying who sent the data right? It can only be two values "me" and "system". When getting userMessages from database you have written `WHERE sent = 'me'`. So, how do you get sent=abc above?

Comment: The code in the dao class you are mention is @Query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sent = 'me'")
    fun getUserMessages(): LiveData<List<Conversation>>  but this is not being used anymore. I was trying to fetch only the user  messages to see what the problem is, But now only the getAllmessages function is being used which fetches both the system and user  messages in a manner -- Retrieved message from database: sent=abc, received= xyz.  Here sent implies the message sent from the user and received implies the message user is getting from the system.

Comment: Also I have updated the main fragment code so you can refer to that without any confusion

Comment: Did you update your `getItemViewType()` method accordingly? Because when  sent equals me then only you setting view type for user message. `when(messageList[position].sent){ "me" -> 0 // "ai" -> 1 else -> 1 }} `

Comment: Also, are you trying to use two list items in your recycler from single item in your messageList? So, for one message you will have two layouts one for sent message and one for received message, right? If this is case you can add both layouts in one list_item_layout file and then if add text to those with only one ViewHolder. If in case some sent or received message is null? You can set its visibility to false.

Comment: I think the problem is because, you have two viewHolders and you want both of them to be populated for single list item. `getItemViewType()` returns only one ViewType. and since your else condition is set to 1. You are only getting system messages. Change your else condition to 0, check if you get only user messages. To solve this you can used above mentioned approach.

Comment: I am using two layouts one for sent messages and one for received messages these contains card view that contains text views in them and then making both of them to show in another layout which has recycler view using the adapter. Are you suggesting me to use only one layout containing both the messages in it and then populate the recycler view with it.

Comment: Yes use only only layout. Because you have two layout and one message will populate only one layout. But you want to populate both layouts with one message. So, create only one layout. You can make it on opposite sides as you want like chat. And, in case suppose received text is null for some message than you can hide that textView for that. I hope you understand, why your code wasn't working.

Comment: If you want to have separate layouts, you will have to change your Conversation data model. Do let me know, if you want that, I will provide steps and code for that implementation.

Comment: Yes please if you have any solution for that it would be of great help. I think the main issue is not in the fragment but in the adapter class, as both previous user and system messages that are saved are retrieving properly from the database but only the system messages are showing in the recycler view. When inserting a new user message they are getting removed as soon as the system message is adding.

Comment: Did you try using a single layout file? Because for the approach of having different layouts will require changing how you add data in database as well.

Comment: I tried using only single layout and changed the adapter to class MessageRVAdapter(private var messageList: ArrayList<MessageRVModel>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() { class MessageViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val leftChatLayout: LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.leftchat)
    val rightChatLayout: LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rightchat)
    val leftChatText: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.leftchattext)
    val rightChatText: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rightchattext)
}

Comment: the onCreateViewHolderval is view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_conversation, parent, false)
        return MessageViewHolder(view)
    } 
 override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when(messageList[position].sent){
            "me" -> 0
            else -> 1


        }

Comment: the onBindViewHolder {
    val message = messageList[position]
    val sent = messageList.get(position).sent
    if (holder is MessageViewHolder) {
       if (message.sent == "me"){
                holder.rightChatLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                holder.leftChatLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                holder.rightChatText.text = message.sent
            }else {holder.leftChatLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                holder.rightChatLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                holder.leftChatText.text = message.received
            }}}

Comment: But this is not working properly if you have any solution to solve this either by using one layout or two layouts please help

Comment: I don't understand why you have ` (message.sent == "me")` this condition. Earlier you said the sent text means, message sent by user and received means message from system. Then why are you checking this?

Comment: Can you make clear what your Coversation data model's each field is.  What does sent and received mean, is it text message send by user and system respectively?

Comment: Yes, the sent implies the text message sent by the user and the received implies the message that the system gave. The timestamp implies the current time when the message was added. And the data class is -- data class MessageRVModel(  var sent: String,
    var received: String,
    val timestamp: Long)       class Message{
    var SENT_BY_ME = "me"
    var SENT_BY_AI = "ai"
}

Comment: @VivekJaiswal I have added a new answer maybe try that

Comment: where is the new answer

Comment: The one in which I have attached the output screenshot as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout, that will hold both user message and system message. This is simple layout, you can add background, colors and borders to make it more like a chat.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sent_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/received_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Create a `messageAdapter` like this.

```
package com.example.android.sample

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MessageAdapter(private var messageList: ArrayList<Message>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.message_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val message = messageList[position] // get current message
        if (message.sent != null) { // if sent text is not null, we show sent text
            holder.sentMessageTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.sentMessageTextView.text = message.sent
        } else {
            holder.sentMessageTextView.visibility = View.GONE   // reset visibility
        }
        if (message.received != null) { // if received text is not null, we show received text
            holder.receivedMessageTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.receivedMessageTextView.text = message.received
        } else {
            holder.receivedMessageTextView.visibility = View.GONE // reset visibility
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return messageList.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val sentMessageTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sent_message)
        val receivedMessageTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.received_message)
    }
}
```

Link your adapter to recycler view in Activity. I have only sent and received text in Message data class, you can add timestamp as well.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val messageList: ArrayList<Message> = generateSampleMessage()
        val recycler: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.message_recycler)
        val adapter = MessageAdapter(messageList)
        recycler.adapter = adapter
    }

    private fun generateSampleMessage(): ArrayList<Message> {
        // I have used sample values in the List you can get it from your view model and database.
        val messageList = ArrayList<Message>()
        messageList.add(Message("Hi, I am user", "Hi, I am System"))
        messageList.add(Message("How are you System? ", "I am good!!"))
        messageList.add(Message(null, "And, How are you User?"))
        messageList.add(Message("I am also good", null))
        messageList.add(Message(null, "What help you need ?"))
        messageList.add(Message("I need help in this... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis. Quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem. Posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus. Dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies leo. Adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique. ", "Let me help you"))
        return messageList
    }
}
```

Sample Output

[image]